# 74674982327500000000 = 7.47E+19 in Excel become 07467498232750E7 in SQL Big Query. The "E" becomes an alphabet instead of the multiplication

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need the "**E**" to multiply the number instead of being an alphabet because I want to **filter** based on their **length**. The number belongs to a column whose **schema** is set to **strings** because most of the value are **unique ids** made up of a combination of alphabets and numbers. Only a few of them wrongly made up of just numbers.

[image: Excel]

[image: SQL]

Comment: Why do the first two rows look like HEX (and not like scientific E-notation at all)? And why is the last row 0746..E7, when this is clearly much different than 7.47 E+19? Or is the last row *also* actually 'just HEX', with ..E7 thrown in confusingly?

Comment: Perhaps the ride_id column in Excel should be *text* instead of *numeric*?

Comment: The first 2 rows is the right format. The column ride_id should be made up of both alphabets and numbers. But a few of them just contain number. If I filter length in Excel, there 20,19,18,16 and 15. Filter in SQL only give me 16 all. Meaning the E become an alphabet instead of multiplication.

Comment: *cough* Tell excel to [treat the values in the column as text](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/format-numbers-as-text-583160db-936b-4e52-bdff-6f1863518ba4) (and not numbers); or use an equation of the same. The column values should look the same in both cases. Excel might also need to be told to import the data 'as text', as sometimes it can become confused and lose information in an import.

Comment: You can't have in SQL in 1 column some rows should be text and some ints.

Comment: Wrt my previous comment, specifically, Excel has opinionated auto-rules on reading values that "look like" numbers (see the tips section in the link) and thus can pre-lose information in cases that can't be correctly re-constituted. This can be avoided when using formula instead of literal numbers, eg. `="001234"`.

Comment: The column in Excel set to General. The number is not a formula. 07467498232750 add 7 zeros to it and it become the same value in Excel. Like i said, SQL is treating the E as an alphabets instead of multiplication.

Comment: The suggestion was to *make* it a formula (or rather, an expression retuning a string) in Excel so it won’t be treated as a number (ever). And when passing off downstream this should also remain a string.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure if your concern is passing the data from BigQuery into CSV (and then the Excel data is wrong) or from Excel (CSV) into BigQuery (and then, BigQuery data notation is wrong).

**From CSV to BigQuery**

Simply modify the excel column format to [text](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/format-numbers-as-text-583160db-936b-4e52-bdff-6f1863518ba4) instead automatic or scientific notation.

This will change the `6.46E+08` into `646000000`, and then just export this data as CSV and upload into your BigQuery table. Then BigQuery should import the value as `646000000`.

You can also (but not really recommended) cast the `6.46E08` from bigquery into `BIGNUMERIC` and then cast into string again, and update the BigQuery value:

```
UPDATE `{PROJECT_ID}.{DATASET}.{TABLE}` 
SET spec_id=CAST(CAST(spec_id AS BIGNUMERIC) AS STRING) 
WHERE SAFE_CAST(spec_id AS BIGNUMERIC) IS NOT NULL
```

This will calculate all the numbers ended with `E` into plain number

**From BigQuery into CSV**

If you are using excel, you should be able to configure the import settings and request for treat the `spec_id` as literal.

Otherwise, you can always recover the BigQuery data with the `"` and import it directly.

```
SELECT CONCAT('"',spec_id,'"') as spec_id, ...  
FROM `{PROJECT_ID}.{DATASET}.{TABLE}` 
LIMIT 1000
```